# Executing shell-script with parameters using apache.commons.exec in Windows

Tags: java, apache, shell, apache-commons-exec

I am trying to run a script using apache-commons-exec which was implemented using the java approximation to run. This script is executed in the production server (Linux) but I need to test it in my localhost to see that everything works OK.

Here is my code to launch cygwin and this code is working in the cmd.exe but it does not work when I try to launch it using commons.exec:

```
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    exec.setWatchdog(new ExecuteWatchdog(1000));
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);
    exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
    CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash");
    cmdLine.addArgument("-c");
    cmdLine.addArgument("/cygdrive/c/dev/launch.sh");
    int exit = exec.execute(cmdLine);
    logger.warn("Job exit: " + exit);
```

It returns 1 and no output or log error:

```
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

Is there anything missing? How can I catch the output properly?

Comment: ... test it in a Linux environment. You bash script can have a she-bang #!/bin/bash and sticky uid bit chmod s+u. (The windows cygwin environment is started with bash --login -i )

Comment: Not possible thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess this but might help.

Sometimes an `exit code = 1` represents "success". However, Apache Commons Exec by default interprets an `exit code = 1` as a failure and will throw an `ExecuteException` if the script in question exits with and `exit code = 1`.

You can tell your `DefaultExecutor` that "`exit code = 1` = success" using the following code:

```
exec.setExitValue(1);
```

Might not be the reason but worth a go.

Comment: I checked everything and I think the problem is the following: When the exit is 1 there is no output stream (can't see echo or stderr in my log) whereas I can see echos when exit is 0